# Linking C and CXX files in CMake

Tags: c++, c, linker, cmake

I'm building C++ app with CMake. But it uses some source files in C. Here is simplified structure:

trunk/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(myapp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -Wall")
add_subdirectory (src myapp)
```

trunk/src/main.cpp:

```
#include "smth/f.h"
int main() { f(); }
```

trunk/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory (smth)
link_directories (smth)    
set(APP_SRC main)
add_executable (myapp ${APP_SRC})
target_link_libraries (myapp smth)
```

trunk/src/smth/f.h:

```
#ifndef F_H
#define F_H
void f();
#endif
```

trunk/src/smth/f.c:

```
#include "f.h"
void f() {}
```

trunk/src/smth/CMakeLists.txt

```
set (SMTH_SRC some_cpp_file1 some_cpp_file2 f)
add_library (smth STATIC ${SMTH_SRC})
```

The problem is: i run gmake, it compiles all the files and when it links all libs together, i get:

```
undefined reference to `f()` in main.cpp
```

if i rename f.c into f.cpp everything goes just fine. What's the difference and how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: A good read about this: `Mixing C and C++:` http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change f.h to:

```
#ifndef F_H
#define F_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void f();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add C guards to all your C files. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c) for more details