# Calling c function in a lib file from c++

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have to call a c function declared in a lib file from c++. What instructions/attributes/configuration I have to set for this?

Comment: Why not put that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a header file for the library? If so it should have

```
extern "C" {
blah blah
}
```

stuff in it to allow it to be used by C programs. If not, then you can put that around the include statement for the header in your own code. E.g.

```
extern "C" {
    #include "imported_c_library.h"
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work! You need # before include, and no ; at the end.

Comment: I was typing a bit too quickly. Need to re-read before hitting the button.

Answer (score 2):

ensure you put extern "C" before the declaration of the function if it isn't already in the header.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing the header files yourself, it's often nice to do something like this

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

...

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

so that this gets ignored by your c compiler, but picked up by c++ one.  Incidentally, for a good discussion of why you need this, check out

[Why do we need extern "C"{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)