# extern keyword in c

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need extern “C”{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)

many a times in our code i have seen some statements like following:

```
extern "C" {

//some code

        };
```

what does this exactly mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of (or rather, covered by) [Why do we need extern "C"{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It tells the C++ compiler that "some code" must be compiled in C style. This allows the linkage between C and C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

It tells the compiler to treat the following code as C code and not as c++ code

Answer (score 0):

More to the point, functions with C++ linkage will not be found by the linker when called from a C function unless you specify that the functions should have the same linkage type.
So you'll get all sorts of link errors, which won't seem obvious as to why.