# C preproccessor problem

Tags: c++

I have a program to find the reciprocal of a number but the main program is written in C and the `reciprocal` function is written in c++.Next I have a header file `reciprocal.hpp` that has some of the conditional compilation code that makes the `reciprocal` function an extern function.Can someone please explain me what is there in the `reciprocal.hpp` program.

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
int i;
i = atoi(argv[1]);
printf("\nThe reciprocal of %d is %f\n",i,reciprocal(i));
return 0;
}
```

**reciprocal.cpp**

```
#include<cassert>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"

double reciprocal(int i)
{
assert( i != 0);
return 1.0/i;
}
```

**reciprocal.hpp**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern double reciprocal(int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I don't understand what is happening in `reciprocal.hpp`.Please help!!

Comment: Your question really is about C++. Tag replaced. I believe the `extern "C"` thingamaging prevents the C++ compiler from doing *name-mangling*

Comment: possible duplicate of [extern "C"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/extern-c)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c

Comment: @interjay: Not an exact duplicate (but close) as this also deals with the pre-processor and how to handle the difference between C/C++

Comment: @pmg: It does a bit more. It forces the compiler to use the C ABI. This mean a couple of difference in how code is generated. For Example: passing parameters/return value on the stack in C (usually). passing parameters and return values via registers if the compiler deems this to be more efficient in C++(usually). As in all examples your mileage may very with compiler and optimization settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the `ifdef`s, they simply allow the function to be exported to C if the header is compiled as C++. The `extern` line simply defines a function prototype for `reciprocal`.

Answer (score 7):

C++ compilers always define the `__cplusplus` symbol. So, what the header is doing is wrapping the prototype in

```
extern "C" { ... }
```

This tells the compiler not to perform [name mangling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Name_mangling) on whatever is enclosed within that block. Now, the C code can refer to the function by its original name as if it were a C function.

Comment: why the need for two #ifdef __cplusplus

Comment: The `extern "C"` declaration only applies to the statement immediately following it. To make it apply to several statements you enclose all those statements within the `{}` block. The second `#ifdef` is to switch the closing brace in and out.