# Do I need an extern "C" block to include standard POSIX C headers?

Tags: c++, posix-api

Do I need an `extern "C" {}` block to include standard C headers in a C++ program. Only consider standard C headers which do not have counterparts in C++.

For example:

```
extern "C" {
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
}
```

Comment: Just found this question that's similar to yours: [Why do we need extern “C”{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior of `<fcntl.h>` and `<unistd.h>` in C++ is not specified by the standard (because they are also not part of the C89 standard).  That said, I have never seen a platform where they (a) exist and (b) actually need to be wrapped in an `extern "C"` block.

The behavior of `<stdio.h>`, `<math.h>`, and the other standard C headers is specified by section D.5 of the C++03 standard.  They do not require an `extern "C"` wrapper block, and they dump their symbols into the global namespace.  However, everything in Annex D is "deprecated".

The canonical C++ form of those headers is `<cstdio>`, `<cmath>`, etc., and they are specified by section 17.4.1.2 (3) of the C++ standard, which says:

```
<cassert> <ciso646> <csetjmp> <cstdio> <ctime> <cctype> <climits>
<csignal> <cstdlib> <cwchar> <cerrno> <clocale> <cstdarg> <cstring>
<cwctype>
```

> Except as noted in clauses 18 through 27, the contents of each header
>   cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h, as
>   specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming Languages C (Clause 7), or
>   ISO/IEC:1990 Programming Languages—C AMENDMENT 1: C Integrity, (Clause
>   7), as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ Standard Library,
>   however, the declarations and definitions (except for names which are
>   defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.5) of the
>   namespace std.

So the standard, non-deprecated, canonical way to use (e.g.) `printf` in C++ is to `#include <cstdio>` and then invoke `std::printf`.

Comment: The behavior of `<fcntl.h>` and `<unistd.h>` *is* specified by the POSIX standard -- POSIX requires that these header files be usable directly by the supported C or C++ compiler without anything additional -- so essentially, they're required to have a embedded, guarded `extern "C"` or something else equivalent for all supported compilers.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - That is true for C, of course. Can you cite any POSIX document that says these headers must "be usable directly" in C++?

Answer (score 24):

The system C headers usually already include a `extern "C"` block, guarded by `#ifdef __cplusplus`. This way the functions automatically get declared as `extern "C"` when compiled as C++ and you don't need to do that manually.

For example on my system `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h` start with `__BEGIN_DECLS` and end with `__END_DECLS`, which are macros defined in `sys/cdefs.h`:

```
/* C++ needs to know that types and declarations are C, not C++.  */
#ifdef   __cplusplus
# define __BEGIN_DECLS  extern "C" {                                            
# define __END_DECLS }
#else
# define __BEGIN_DECLS
# define __END_DECLS
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do. However, many systems (notably Linux) are already adding an `extern "C"` bracketing like you do. See (on Linux) files `/usr/include/unistd.h` `/usr/include/features.h` and the macro  `__BEGIN_DECLS` defined in `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h` and used in many Linux system include files.

So on Linux, you usually can avoid your `extern "C"` but it does not harm (and, IMHO, improve readability in that case).

Comment: "does not harm"? But I was told "You shouldn't even need to do that (the extra extern "C" {}) in most cases as they are system headers. You can actually break things doing that as some have C++ only exports". Is that true?  I just asked a question here [Are most linux system headers C++ compatiable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417324/are-most-linux-system-headers-c-compatiable)

Answer (score 2):

No, you should use the C++ wrapper headers (for instance like `<cstdio>`). Those take care of all that for you.

If it's a header that doesn't have those, then yes, you'll want to wrap them in `extern "C" {}`.

**ETA:** It's worth noting that many implementations will include the wrapper inside the .h file like below, so that you can get away with not doing it yourself.

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `<cstdio>` etc. headers technically put their definitions in the `std` namespace.  (Many implementations also put them in the top-level namespace, but that is not what the standard says.)

Answer (score 0):

the macro __BEGIN_DECLS defined in /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h and used in many Linux system include files.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It *is* a good idea to let the compiler know so that it can expect C code when compiling as C++. You might also find that the header files themselves contain `extern "C" {` as guards.

For example, `curses.h` on my system contains:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
...
```

Comment: *"let the compiler know so that it can expect C code when compiling as C++"* - That's not what `extern "C"` does. It doesn't change the interpretation of code. It doesn't even apply to code. It's a language linkage directive that instructs the compiler to generate symbols compatible with those the linker expects for C. It makes C++ code callable from C, but doesn't change code generation.

Comment: @IInspectable Doesn't _"instructs the compiler to generate symbols compatible with those the linker expects for C"_ imply that it applies to code, or at least the calling convention of code? It is definitely letting the compiler (as well as the linker) know something.

Comment: @Tanz87: It doesn't change code generation one bit. The generated object code is identical with or without `extern "C"`. The directive applies to symbol naming only. It has no bearing on calling conventions.

Answer (score -1):

I just double checked the stdlib.h for the GNU compiler and the declarations do not use extern "C" as declarations.

edit:

```
if defined __cplusplus && defined _GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES
define __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD    namespace std {
```

So including the old headers will place declarations on std provided _GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES is defined?