# C Compiler error from standard headers - undefined C++ definitions

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile a C program, but receive many errors.

The errors are encountered in standard C headers files (inttypes.h, stdio.h, stat.h, etc).

The source of the errors are the following undefined constants:

__BEGIN_DECLS
__END_DECLS
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
__END_NAMESPACE_STD
__THROW
__CONCAT

What these constants seem to have in common is that they are defined differently depending on whether the C or C++ compiler is being used.

For example, this question [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087438/should-i-have-to-use-an-extern-c-block-to-include-the-c-headers/8087539#8087539) shows the following definition for __BEGIN_DECLS

```
/* C++ needs to know that types and declarations are C, not C++.  */
#ifdef   __cplusplus
# define __BEGIN_DECLS  extern "C" {                                            
# define __END_DECLS }
#else
# define __BEGIN_DECLS
# define __END_DECLS
#endif
```

Any guesses as to why I'm encountering these errors?

Comment: What platform do you run your compiler on ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I'm using gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:

These constants were supposed to be defined in sys/cdefs.h.

For some reason this file was in /usr/include/bsd/sys/cdefs.h.

The bsd version of cdefs.h did not have these constants defined.

I removed the bsd directory and reinstalled libc6-dev.

Everything appears to be working now.

Comment: @poljpocket, you can't mark your own answer to your own question for 2 days.