# Raspberry Pi -fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi2, libgcc, gcc5

I'm trying to compile gcc5.3.0 on my Raspberry Pi with latest Raspbian system image.

```
$ ./configure --enbale-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --host=arm-cortexa7_neon-linux-gnueabihf --build=arm-cortexa7_neon-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-cortexa7_neon-linux-gnueabihf
$ make
```

However, the original compiler (gcc4.9) complains about not founding sys/cdefs.h when compiling libgcc.

I checked I have `libc6-dev` and `build-essential` installed.

So I used `grep -R 'cdefs' /usr/include/` to search it and I found it at /usr/include/bsd/. I created the sys directory and made hard links to these headers under /usr/include/bsd/sys.

This time it gave me a more weird error, 
/usr/include/stdio.h:312:8: error: unknown type name 'FILE'.

I searched this on stackoverflow, and there's a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047237/5691005. But when I removed /usr/include/sys and /usr/include/bsd, then reinstalled libc6-dev, I  cannot find sys/cdefs.h under /usr/include, and the compiler gave errors still.

I'm now totally lost. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with compiling gcc-8.2. I tried to do as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470796/fatal-error-sys-cdefs-h-no-such-file-or-directory) with reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6 libc6-dev
```

After that I was locating all missing headers:

```
find / -name cdefs.h
```

and copying them to /usr/include:
those steps allowed only to move forward but I still didn't manage to completely build gcc.

The best solution I found is to download compiled version of gcc-8.1 from:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/07/raspberry-pi-raspbian-compiling-gcc/

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem when creating a containerized build environment for cross-compiled Qt applications for raspberry pi 4.

I found I needed to edit the mkspec for the linux-rasp-pi4-v3d device and add another cflag so that gcc could find the header from my Raspi sysroot that was used to cross-compile Qt.

Specifically under `qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++/qmake.conf`:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -I$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```