# Why could c++ include <stdio.h> and invoke printf method which is c(platform:ubuntu 14.04 compiler:gcc 4.8.4)

Tags: c++, linker

c++ compiler could compile code like this, and it executed correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("test...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I think printf.c will be compiled to printf.o with c compiler, I just checked the stdio.h, there is no extern "C" keyword, then how could c++ linker link printf in printf.o which is compiled with c compiler?(By the way, my platform is ubuntu 14.04, compiler is gcc 4.8.4)

Comment: Just because the `C` standard library contains a `printf()` doesn't mean the `C++` standard library can't provide one too. Mostly it is included to allow easy migration of source code written in `C` being ported to `C++`.

Comment: @Galik: Which is a good way to mess all up, as C is a different language with relevant differences even for identical syntax. But there still has to be specified the C calling conventions to the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Olaf The `C++` standard recommends `C++` language linkage for the `C library` functions but leaves the actual decision to the implementation - so they *can* use `extern "C" {}` if they choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can give you a definitive answer without knowing what implementation you're using.

Cheers and hth. - Alf gave one possibility, which is that the `stdio.h` that is included by a C++ program may not be the same as the `stdio.h` that is included by a C program. Another possibility is that it is the same header, and there *is* an `extern "C"` block, and you just can't see it. For example, I use gcc, and my `/usr/include/stdio.h` contains a `__BEGIN_DECLS` macro, which expands to `extern "C" {` when compiled as C++. See [Do I need an extern "C" block to include standard C headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087438/do-i-need-an-extern-c-block-to-include-standard-c-headers)

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is part of the C++ standard library.

The `<stdio.h>` header that you include in the C++ source, belongs to the C++ standard library, and is not necessarily the same contents as a C compiler will include.

How the C++ implementation leverages the corresponding C implementation (if at all) is an implementation detail.

Comment: Platform is ubuntu 14.04, compiler is gcc 4.8.4

Answer (score 2):

When C++ was originally made it was effectively a superset of C. That is to say, you can code perfectly good C in the C++ environment, just by ignoring all of the features that C++ adds. That, and because nowadays most C compilers are C++ compilers in which you can code C, is why you can use `printf`.

Secondly, no object code is generated for stdio because it is already a library, and so you are linking your own .o code against the already compiled stdio library code, which will be located somewhere in your compilers directory.

Comment: Nowadays, it's impossible to write good C code in C++. The second part of your answer isn't answer the question w.r.t. extern C

Answer (score -1):

You may not see an explicit `extern "C"` in stdio.h, but it is there. It's just hiding.

For example, on Linux, in stdio.h we see this:

```
#include <features.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS
```

In `<features.h>` you will find the following:

```
# ifndef _SYS_CDEFS_H
#  include <sys/cdefs.h>
# endif
```

And in `<sys/cdefs.h>` you finally see:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
# define __BEGIN_DECLS  extern "C" {
# define __END_DECLS    }
#else
# define __BEGIN_DECLS
# define __END_DECLS
#endif
```

So, via a fairly roundabout path, Linux header files have a `__BEGIN_DECLS/__END_DECLS` wrapper which, when compiled by a C++ compiler, end up wrapping the whole thing inside `extern "C"`.

Comment: **−1** Re "but it is there", no, not necessarily. That is dis-information.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you mean __BEGIN_DECLS in stdio.h is not necessary?

Comment: @cong: In some cases the C++ library provides overloads of C library functions. For a given function name at most one of those overloads can have C linkage, or the linker couldn't distinguish them. Then why should any of them have C linkage? The C++ standard does not require C linkage of these functions. That's just disinformation.