# How non standard c headers (unistd.h, fcntl.h, ...) work with c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, posix

As far as i know, whenever we use a code compiled in [c](/questions/tagged/c) in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) we have to specify a linkage convention for example,

```
extern "C" {
    void func1(void);
    void func2(int, double);
}
```

The use of `extern "C"` says that (*lack of reference link*):

> it should be linked according to the C linkage convention. All
>   functions in standard C library are written in this way like (stdio.h,
>   cstdio, stdlib.h, ...)

Now coming to system headers like **`unistd.h`, `fcntl.h`**, if you view the contents, it is just a normal C header without any `extern "C"` surrounding them.

Now, when used in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code it is compiling without any errors.

These are my questions:

1. Why it is linking without any errors.
2. Should i include the header like this so it works every time.

   extern "C" {
      #include 
   }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087539/918959

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I think it is reasonable to undelete your answer. OP likely made a mistake concluding the headers did not (effectiveky) contain `extern “C”`, and addressing that directly is better than simply referring to the other question, where this aspect is not prominent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I googled only when I had found the `__BEGIN_DECLS` using that as the keyword, since an answer to the other question does mention that too, and it talks about the exact same 2 headers, not much left for my answer :D