# Are most linux system headers C++ compatiable?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Are most linux system headers/API C++ compatiable?

Today I was trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
}


int main() {
  //socket exercise
}
```

Then I was told by a friend:

> shouldn't even need to do that (**the extra extern "C" {}**) in most cases as they are system headers.
>   try it first and then worry about it.
>   don't assume system headers aren't compatible.
>   You can actually break things doing that as some have C++ only exports

Bu then I asked:

> If I include a C library function and compile without error. Does it ensure that the library I included is C++ compatiable and then I can safely use it?

The answer is:

> No, there's no checking.

---

So try it first --> no error --> doesn't ensure that it's C++ compatiable.

Then what should I do for example with Linux system headers? Because I can't simply wrap the system headers with an extra `extern "C" {}` statement ("I might actually break things doing that as some have C++ only exports").

So I need to check if there are `__BEGIN_DECLS` and `__END_DECLS` MARCOS defined in the system header file for each header file I use? If not, then I need to wrap it with `extern "C" {}`? Otherwise I just include it directly?

FYI, `__BEGIN_DECLS` and `__END_DECLS` are defined as:

```
# define __BEGIN_DECLS  extern "C" {
# define __END_DECLS    }
```

Comment: Compiling without errors most certainly does not mean that they're compatible... but yes, most headers that *can* be made compatible *are so* and those that aren't probably wouldn't become any better by wrapping them in `extern "C" {}`

Comment: It's not a strict duplicate, but this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087438/do-i-need-an-extern-c-block-to-include-standard-c-headers, which might give some insight.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Then what's the **best practice** I should have? Like I said, check those marcos first and then decide?

Comment: All the POSIX headers will be fine. And for `GNU/Linux` all system headers will be `C++` friendly. Third party libraries you will need to check. (eg `libffmpeg`)

Comment: @Galik Ok thanks. But to be curious, where did you know that "for GNU/Linux all system headers will be C++ friendly."? I mean.. I was told by someone.. And I should have known that from the Internet. I've almost finished reading *APUE* and it doesn't mention it at all!

Comment: @Rick I am currently looking for documentation. But the `GNU` project that wrote the `GNU` operating system that runs on most Linux (desktop) implementations also wrote the `GNU C/C++` compiler and their headers are naturally `C++` friendly.

Comment: @Galik That deduction would be pretty hard for a newbie... I can't just persuade myself on everything by guessing. ;D (I know you are looking for documenation, thank you )

Comment: @Rick Yes I see that. I am also pretty sure POSIX specifies that their headers should be C++ friendly (GNU OS is a POSIX implementation) but I'm having trouble proving it :)

Comment: @Galik Ok got it. :) Told by 2 experts then a newbie can only take it as a yes. :). But is that true: "You can actually break things doing that as some have C++ only exports", if I add extra `extern "C"` block? I saw opposite opinion here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087530/5983841

Comment: @Demosthenes Thank you that's helpful.