# Expanding existing ESP-IDF project to make an HTTP call

Tags: c, cmake, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf

Trying to expand [this project](https://github.com/m5stack/M5Dial-UserDemo) with a simple additional function - make a HTTP GET call.

1. I have downloaded [this HTTP client](https://components.espressif.com/components/parabuzzle/http_rest_client) and put it in the compoenents folder
2. I made sure the `CMakeLists.txt` file exists with the following content

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE app_sources "./src/*.c")

idf_component_register(
                    SRCS ${app_sources}
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "./include"
                    REQUIRES esp_http_client esp-tls json
                    )
```

3. I then proceed to add `#include <http_rest_client.h>` in one of the apps, specifically in `main\apps\app_temp_demo\gui\gui_temp_demo.cpp`
4. Added a function that perform the call as per example(s) in [the library repo](https://components.espressif.com/components/parabuzzle/http_rest_client)

```
void sendrequest()
{
    http_rest_recv_buffer_t response_buffer = {0};

    // do the request
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(http_rest_client_get("https://catoftheday.com/", &response_buffer));

    char buffer[50]; // Buffer to hold the resulting string
    int status_code = response_buffer.status_code; // Your status code
    sprintf(buffer, "Status Code %d", status_code); // Write to buffer

    // print response status
    // sprintf("Status Code %d", response_buffer.status_code);

    // do something with the data
    printf("%s", response_buffer.buffer);

    // clean up
    http_rest_client_cleanup(&response_buffer);    
}
```

Up to this point building the project (`idf.py build`) is a success, unfortunately once I add a call to hte sendrequest function I get the following warnings/errors:

[image]

It feels like the library isnt picked up and built. Any suggestion on what I might be missing or potentially a better approach i.e. differnt library, etc?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which represent **textual** information. Instead, we expect that information to be in the question post as text. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta. BTW, I would expect a user with a near 1k reputation to be aware about such policy...

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, I wasn't sure which part of the output is relevant to the underlying issue hence a screenshot. I will update the question.
P.S. Do they have any policies about snotty and bigoted commentary? As a contributor of your calibre, it is imperative that you are aware of maintaining a friendly and respectful tone. You can familiarize yourself with the [friendly attitude policies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here after scanning the projects you are referencing, but I think you are missing the `extern C`   hence your want to use a `C` library in a `C++` project.
Adding something like

```
extern "C"{
#include <http_rest_client.h> 
}
```

should help. [Alternatively you could adapt the header files of the referenced component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694605/how-to-use-c-source-files-in-a-c-project/51912672#51912672).