# Duplicate symbols in iOS universal framework (i386)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm using [iOS Universal framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)
template.

I created framework and added them as sub project to another project.
And added framework binaries to the project.

in my framework there is some constants

```
const float kToolbarHeight = 45;
```

And when i'm trying to Build my Project and included Framework for
iphone simulator (i386), there are linker errors:

> ```
> ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

but when i build it for device - there is not any linker errors.

I'm tried to exclude subProject (my framework) from Project, and and keep only binaries, but there is not any effect.

I'm trying to change architectures in targets to the `i386`, and to the `$(VALID_ARCHS)`, as
described in [that](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/30) issue, but there is not any effect.

How can I build framework for iOS simulator, what settings of target should I use?

**Update:** The problem was resolved when I defined
my constants as extern in header file.

```
// MyView.h

extern const float kToolbarHeight;

// MyView.m

const float kToolbarHeight = 45;
```

But why? What difference in simulator and arm builds?

Comment: yup that is how you do it... go ahead and write it as an answer an accept it, it may help someone in the future.

Comment: ok @GradyPlayer , but, I do not understand, why it worked while I do not wrote "extern" in ARM builds?

Comment: different linker... different wanings... ? it really doesn't help to wonder way the wrong thing sometimes works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I defined my constants as extern in header file.

```
// MyView.h

extern const float kToolbarHeight;

// MyView.m

const float kToolbarHeight = 45;
```

[about extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)