# I am really confused with this kind of compilation error( C ffmpeg Qt)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, compilation, ffmpeg

I downloaded the latest ffmpeg source code and successfully installed it on Ubuntu
But I failed to compile a simple demo.(I did included proper headers)

Here are the error messages ,just to name a few:

```
error: unknown type name 'AVFrame'

error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)

error: request for member 'streams' in something not a structure or union

error: 'AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared (first use in this function)

error: expected expression before ')' token
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Contents Added:

e.g this is my includes

```
extern "C"{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
int i, videoStreamIdx;
AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;
AVCodec *pCodec;
AVFrame *pFrame;
AVFrame *pFrameRGB;
```

e.g AVFormatContext is declared in /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h
error message box shows Unknown type name AVFormatContext
But How could it possibly be?

Comment: Need to see some code.

Comment: Here are some additional info
ffmpeg version 1.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on May 7 2013 14:10:58 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) configuration: --enable-gpl --prefix=/usr --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads

And this is the actuall CODE

https://github.com/phamquy/FFmpeg-tu...r/tutorial01.c


This is created in Qt and the Qt pro file.
Quote:
QT -= gui
TEMPLATE = app SOURCES += \ ../tutorial01.c
LIBS += -L/-lavcodec -lavformat -lswscale -lavutil

Comment: possible duplicate of [compiling errors with ffmpeg on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413368/compiling-errors-with-ffmpeg-on-linux)

Comment: yep,the previous one was closed marked as "Not a real Question".But It bugs me and I need to fix it to continue the project.thank you.

Comment: You say you're including proper headers, but the compiler doesn't seem to think you are. Perhaps you could post some code that fails to compile; otherwise it's just your word against the compiler's.

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: And add perhaps the `-H` option to the (`gcc` or `g++`) compiler flags, it will show you the actually included headers.

Comment: Why can't you use the *ffmpeg* provided by your distribution, i.e. install the `libffms2-dev` package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt you can add this line to your `.pro` file to force the compiler to look there for header files. Change it to the folder where your header files are stored.

`INCLUDEPATH += <your path>`

Comment: I solved the issue. the project is compiled with g++ while the suffix of the source file is .c  so the solution is change it to .cpp

Answer (score 1):

for C++ code ,

```
extern "C"
{
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
#include "libavutil/avutil.h"
}
```

for C code ,

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
```

C and C++ compiles in different set of codes.

for more info refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67930/6180077

in main() or very beginning of the program , ffmpeg libraries are need to be initialized

```
av_register_all()  /*Initializes libavformat and registers all the muxers, demuxers and protocols. */
```

while compiling the program (say Ubuntu)

```
-L/$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I/$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include/ myprogram.cpp -o executableFile -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswresample
```