# Linker links correct file, but fails to find symbols

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, ld

I'm playing around with libav*. I wrote a simple program to open a file and output how many streams it has in it, just something to get my feet wet. I link with avformat, avcodec and avutil. However, I get undefined reference errors from ld. The undefined references are all libav* functions. I took a look at the verbose linker output and see that it is linking with the correct libraries and I used objdump to confirm that the symbols are located in the library, but ld still throws undefined reference errors.

Comment: posting your link line and error messages wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: A down vote for a potentially interesting question but badly formated and a hardly reproducible problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you programming in C++? If that's the case, you need to add 'extern "C" {...};'.

Take a look here: [Why do we need extern "C"{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c) 
and note that libav* is written in C.

Comment: Completely forgot that not all C based libraries do this for you.