# Can a mixed C/C++ header include another mixed header?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

After reading [Why do we need extern "C"{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c) I concluded, including a header within the extern "C"-block is fine.

But I ran into problems with this constellation:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "mixedstuff.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

mixedstuff.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "cstuff.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#include "cppstuff.h"
#endif
```

As one can see, I ended up with `cppstuff.h` being included by the C++ compiler within the `extern "C"` block. This caused a lot of errors, because many statements were just not possible with C-linkage.

The obvious solution is to `#include mixedstuff.h` outside the `extern "C"` block. But this requires me to look into each header to see if it is plain **C**, C++ or mixed.

From this I would recommend to make headers C++ aware, rather than including them in extern "C". Am I right, or is there a better way?

Comment: The first usage of __cplusplus was unnecessary because the included .h file already takes care of it.  Which solves the problem of course.  Don't help too much :)

Comment: That's what I meant with "the obvious solution". I tried to ask for a best-practice for such situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I gather that `mixedstuff.h` is designed
to be used in both C and C++.  Which means that it probably has
`#ifdef __cplusplus` etc., with some pure C++ code in places.
In such cases, it should *not* be included inside an `extern "C"` block.  In general, unless explicitly documented otherwise,
most headers should be included at the outermost level, outside
all blocks, namespaces, etc.  The one exception is pure
C headers, where the author has not designed the library to be
used from C++; those must be included within an `extern "C"`
block.  (But from what I've seen, such headers are becoing rarer
and rarer.)

And you shouldn't have to look inside the headers; you need to look at the documentation.

And if you are the author of the header, then you should make it C++ aware (and document this fact, perhaps at the library level).

Answer (score 1):

When the example tells you to put `extern "C"` in yourself, that is when you are including a C-only header.

As it is C-only, it has been possibly written in C for C and so if you want to use it for C++, you need to specify it to being a C header.

IF you have `mixstuff.h` it won't work in C as it has C++ only constructs. Those that are C constructs that you want to have with C linkage you should mark explicitly within `mixstuff.h`. Or isolate them out into their own header.

Note that together with `mixstuff.h` there will somewhere be a `mixstuff.c` or `mixstuff.cpp` being compiled or possibly even two different compilation units. You can us a C++ compiler to compile the implementations, and they can even be C++ (with C linkage) using in their implementations C++ constructs (and often are. You will often give your C++ library a C interface).

If `mixstuff` was build in C++ originally with C++ name mangling it will not link with your code if you now put `extern "C"` around its declarations. If the functions really were built by a C compiler though, you need to use `extern "C"` so you can see them.

Answer (score 1):

There are various C and C++ standards, which have commonalities and differences.

If code is written in the common intersection of all your target-standards, just include it in the global namespace.

If it only misses `extern "C"` when included in C++, wrap it externally.

Otherwise, things get complicated, and you have to patch it directly.

The preprocessor, with conditions on `__cplusplus`, `__STDC_VERSION__` and other feature- and language-test macros, is a way to write code which behaves properly under a wider set of conditions than guaranteed by the general language itself.

Use it wisely, it is easy to misuse.

Comment: +1 for "Use it wisely, it is easy to misuse." I have by now read some about the extern "C"-construct and found no such words of warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure stuff has C++ linkage even though the containing header file might be included inside an `extern "C"` block, you can use an `extern "C++"` block:

```
extern "C++" {
#include "cppstuff.h"
}
```