# Android ndk-build linker fails to find prebuilt library function

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to modify this tutorial to include a prebuilt C library in my Android Studio project (ie. not using the experimental Gradle plugin) http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/

The library itself is coming from a client who won't reveal the source code, therefore I have no control over that part of the build process, however they are already following the same tutorial.

The project builds, load-library works and the NDK link (/jni/my-wrapper.c) works fine, until I try to call the actual library function defined in my prebuild header. The error I'm receiving is:

```
$ ndk-build
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : my-wrapper <= my-wrapper.c
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libmy-wrapper.so
/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/my-wrapper/my-wrapper.o: In function `Java_com_my_project_SignInActivity_CallFunction':
/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/jni/my-wrapper.c:44: undefined reference to `MyFunction'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmy-wrapper.so] Error 1
```

Here's my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# static library info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libMyLib
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libMyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libMyLib.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# wrapper info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../prebuild/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := my-wrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my-wrapper.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libMyLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And MyLib.h (note that foobar() works fine as it's in the header but as long as I'm calling MyFunction from within my-wrapper.c the ndk-build fails):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int MyFunction(some stuff);
int foobar(){return 1;};
```

Finally, my-wrapper.c:

```
#include <MyLib.h>

jbyte Java_com_my_project_SignInActivity_MyFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, some other stuff){

//   return MyFunction(some other stuff which I cast to C types); //linker fails if uncommented

    return foobar(); //works fine
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that MyFunction actually exists in the library? Since you don't have access to the source code, it's probably worth making sure. You can verify this using the `nm` tool included in the Android NDK.

Comment: `nm libMyLib.a` results in `0000458c T _Z12MyFunctionP9my_structPhS1_S1_` - so it looks like it's there unless there's some subtlety I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a C++ mangled name. You can only use it from C++, not from C.

If you really need to call it from C, you might be able to do it like so:

```
extern int _Z12MyFunctionP9my_structPhS1_S1_(/* whatever the function args are */);

jbyte Java_com_my_project_SignInActivity_MyFunction(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, some other stuff) {
    return _Z12MyFunctionP9my_structPhS1_S1_(args);
}
```

That depends on the code you're calling being compatible as such (if that's the case, you should ask the client to build their APIs as `extern "C"`).

I'd really recommend just moving your code to C++ though.

Comment: Incredible! The client is insistent it's a C library though - is it possible they mistakenly compiled a C source to mangle the names into C++, by blindly following step 1 from http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/ ? Would there be any side-effects to me simply transitioning the wrapper code to C++, in which case I should go back to them and ask to build the C lib properly. Sorry for basic questions, a C++ developer I am not!

Comment: Turns out the client had all their C code in .CPP files, which is what was confusing their compiler into producing mangled names instead of pure C libs.

Comment: Yeah, .cpp files will produce C++ mangled names by default. If they want to keep the .cpp files but still keep their API C compatible they just need to wrap their function decls with `extern "C"` (within `#ifdef __cplusplus` like the last snippet in http://stackoverflow.com/a/67985/632035).