# Bitwise operation with constant issue

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, constants, bitwise-operators

This is one of the weirdest things I've encountered. My problem is this:

First of all, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7. In a C++\CLI project, I have code similar tho the following:

```
void Class::function(int flag) 
{
   if ((flag & CONST) != 0)
       printf("Passed.");
   else 
       printf("Failed.");
}
```

Where `CONST` is defined in another (Non-CLR) DLL to be `0x111`. Looks pretty straight-forward. The problem I've had is that when I entered the procedure where `flag` is equal to `0x40`. To me, it looks as if this procedure should print `Failed.`, when in fact it it printed `Passed.`. The next thing I did, was to alter my code to the following:

```
void Class::function(int flag) 
{
   int local = CONST, localRes = flag & local, res;
   if ((res = (flag & CONST)) != 0)
       printf("Passed.");
   else 
       printf("Failed.");
}
```

Now, breaking the execution on `printf`, I got the following values in the Watch:

```
res = 0x110
local = 0x111
localRes = 0x0
```

I could not watch the value of `CONST` though VS didn't didn't know it in that context.

As far as I'm concerned, I could get around this by using `local`, but I'd rather understand it. Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the compilation/execution?
Thanks!

**EDIT:** In the included header file (included as `extern "C"`), it is defined as so:

```
#define CONST /
   C1 | C2 | C3
```

Where quite regularly, `C1` is `0x1`, `C2` is `0x10`, and `C3` is `0x100`.

Comment: How is `CONST` DEFINED?

Comment: Have you tried defining `CONST` as `extern`?

Comment: Maybe this is not so clear.  Particularly the claim "defined in another non-CLR dll" seems quite unlikely, exporting data from a dll isn't very obvious.

Comment: Without any extra information, I expect @ThomasMatthews is onto something.  For example. if `CONST` is a poorly-defined macro, you may have a change in behaviour when you use `flag & CONST` versus `flag & (CONST)`.

Comment: CONST could also be a class overridgin the biwise or operator...

Comment: @jpo38: Not in this case. For that to be an option, it would have to be on the left-hand side of the operator.

Comment: @jpo38 I think you mean the bitwise _and_ operator (not _or_).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I updated my question

Comment: And there we have it.  Case closed.

Comment: In case you missed @paddy's point, the problem is in the definition of the macro. Make it `#define CONST (C1 | C2 | c3)`. The parentheses are crucial.

Comment: @IInspectable: if `CONST` is an instance of `STUPID` class class, one guy could have defined `int operator&( int a, const STUPID& b) { return 1; }`....and `operator int() { return 0x111; }` would have been funny...

Comment: @paddy: Yes, that's what I meant to write!

Comment: @jpo38: That's not a class overriding the operator. That's a free function.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wouldn't change a header file from an external API

Comment: @IInspectable: Agree.

Comment: Then you'll have to put parentheses around every use of `CONST`, because what you now refer to as "an external API" has a serious bug.

Comment: *"included as `extern "C"`"* - I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @PeteBecker Very well, I'll try that. Also, I've already found a lot more serious bugs and inconsistencies in that company's APIs, so that wouldn't surprise me. Thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c

Comment: Further, this demonstrates why you should provide code that actually shows the problem when it's compiled. In the process of creating that code you probably would have uncovered the problem yourself.

Comment: I didn't know the origin of the problem, or I wouldn't have asked here, so when asked for that code, I provided it. I am a veteran C# programmer, but new to C++, and I recently encountered the ugliest compilation bugs, so I thought this problem might've had something to do with VS or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`flag & CONST` expands to `flag & C1 | C2 | C3`, equivalent to `(flag & C1) | C2 | C3`.

**Don't ever `#define` expressions without parentheses**, or operator precedence will bite you.

If you don't have control over the header, either wrap it in your own macro:

```
#define GOOD_CONST (CONST)
```

Or put it in a variable (use `extern` if needed to be exposed in a header):

```
unsigned int GOOD_CONST = CONST;
```

And use only that in your code.

Comment: or: constexpr unsigned GOOD_CONST = CONST;