# difficulty linking c and c++ code in SCONS framework

Tags: c++, scons

I am trying to make a shared library in scons but it keeps telling me there is an error because there is an undefined reference to some functions I wrote. I include the .c file from which I am trying to make the shared library. For some reason it is recognizing the cpp file I am inputting but not the .c file.

Your help would be much appreciated`

```
import os

Import('env')

env = env.Clone()
env.Append(CPPPATH=['include'])
env.Append(LIBS=['serial'])

env.Append(LIBPATH=['/usr/local/lib'])
env.Append(LIBS=['boost_date_time','boost_system', 'boost_thread'])


lib = []
binaries = []

lib.extend(env.SharedLibrary('File1.c', 'File2.cpp']))
print "the error is here"
test_env = env.Clone()
test_env.Append(LIBS=['Program'], LIBPATH=['.'])
binaries.extend([
  test_env.Program('test_Program', Glob('test/test_Adafruit.cpp')),
])

Return('lib', 'binaries')
```

during the linking phase:
I get the errors like:

```
LINK    build/test_Program
build/test_Program/libProgram.so:
```

undefined reference to `function(int, sensor_xyz_s*)'`

Comment: You have your question all wrong. Your question is really how to link C code and C++ code together on your platform, whatever platform it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ don't have the same calling conventions, so C++ does not recognize C functions from other objects. If you're trying to call a C function in File1.c from a C++ function in File2.cpp, you either need to (1) make sure to [declare the C function with `extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985/172599), (2) explicitly use the C++ compiler to create File1.o, or (3) rename File1 to File1.cpp (assuming that your C code is valid C++). The cleanest solution is probably option (1).

To set the C compiler in your SConscript, use:

```
env['CC'] = env['CXX']
```

To tell the C++ code that `function` is a C function, change the *declaration* of the C function to the following. Note that this is just the declaration of the function -- if the declaration is in a header used by both C and C++, you need to wrap the extern "C" so that it's hidden from the C compiler (which may not understand it).

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void function(int, sensor_xyz_s*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: So if, in File1. c there is void func(){}; it needs to be extern "C" {void func(){}}?

Comment: I now get error: conflicting declaration of 'int function(int, sensor_xyz_s*)' with 'C' linkage. Does the header file also have to have the extern "C" around the prototypes?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. You should edit the header file so that there's one declaration of your function that both C and C++ recognize.

Comment: Can you have more than one function in the extern "C" brackets? do I have to edit both the .h and the .c file? or leave the .c file alone and just edit the .h file?

Comment: also where in the Scons file should I set env['CC'] = env['CXX']

Comment: You really shouldn't need to set env['CC'] = env['CXX'].  You can compile the .c with c compiler and .cpp with c++ compiler and have them link correctly without it. (assuming you're using the same version gcc and g++ for example).

Comment: @bdbaddog, you're right, there's no need to all of what I suggested. I was trying to provide several options -- I clarified the answer.