# Why calling objc function from objc++ could result in build failure?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Given this MVP code:

objc_funcs.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString* doFoo(void);
```

objc_funcs.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString* doFoo()
{
    return @"fffuuu";
}
```

main.mm

```
#import "objc_funcs.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    doFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

If I leave it this way, the build will result in

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "doFoo()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Though if I rename `main.mm` -> `main.m`, the build will go just fine.

WAIDW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relates to [C vs C++ linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

The normal way this is handled in C headers is testing for the `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro and inserting an `extern "C"` if needed. `CoreFoundation` provides the `CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN` and `CF_EXTERN_C_END` macros that handle this:

```
#if !defined(CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN)
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN extern "C" {
#define CF_EXTERN_C_END   }
#else
#define CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN
#define CF_EXTERN_C_END
#endif
#endif
```

Using these your `objc_funcs.h` becomes:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN
NSString* doFoo(void);
CF_EXTERN_C_END
```

if you don't want to use them you could use

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
NSString* doFoo(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it valid for C++ compiler by either converting objc_funcs to .mm file or wrapping the import in main.mm with `extern "C" {}`:

```
extern "C" {
#import "objc_funcs.h"
}
```

You could read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)